# How to get the userID of selected users inside the User node?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to build an android app in which I am importing all the contacts present in the phone and then checking that the phone number exists inside the User node or not. If no then the visibility of the itemView will be gone and if yes the visibility will be visible. But once it is visible, **I want to get the id of that specific user** so that I can perform some specific tasks.

**[image: 1]**

**ContactsAdapter.java**

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Activity activity;
    ArrayList<Contacts> arrayList;
    DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");


    public ContactsAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Contacts> arrayList){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull  ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_item, parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ContactsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Contacts model = arrayList.get(position);

        String phoneNo = model.getNumber();
        phoneNo = phoneNo.replaceAll("\\s", "");

        holder.show_name.setText(model.getName());
        holder.show_message.setText(phoneNo);
        holder.notific.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.accReq.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.sendReq.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.timeLast.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.img_on.setVisibility(View.GONE);

       Query query = userRef.orderByChild("phno").equalTo(phoneNo);
       query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
               if (!snapshot.exists()){
                   holder.itemView.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
                   holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               }else {
                   // want to get the userID to perform some click events.
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

           }
       });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView show_message, show_name, timeLast;
        public ImageView personAvatarR, sendReq;
        public CircleImageView img_on,notific;
        public Button accReq;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            accReq = itemView.findViewById(R.id.accReq);
            show_message = itemView.findViewById(R.id.personHolderEmail);
            show_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.personHolderName);
            personAvatarR = itemView.findViewById(R.id.personAvatar);
            timeLast = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeLast);
            img_on = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_on);
            notific = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notific);
            sendReq = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sendReq);
        }
    }
}
```

**getContactList()** method in the ContactActivity

```
private void getContactList() {
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String sort = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC";
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                uri,null,null,null,sort
        );
        if (cursor.getCount()>0){
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                Uri uriPhone = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
                String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID+" =?";

                Cursor  phoneCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                        uriPhone,null,selection,new String[]{id}, null
                );

                if (phoneCursor.moveToNext()){
                    String number = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
                    ));

                    Contacts model = new Contacts();
                    model.setName(name);
                    model.setNumber(number);
                    arrayList.add(model);
                    phoneCursor.close();
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        contactList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new ContactsAdapter(this, arrayList);
        contactList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: in the else part of **ContactsAdapter.java** if I put `final String userName = snapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();` then it will show "null object ref error". If I am not wrong it's because I am trying to get the user info before entering inside a specific child node under the main **Users** node. To enter inside the particular sub child node I need the id of that user so that I can do `userRef.child(userId).` So how to get the user id of specific users(users whose phone no are already saved in contacts). Please help me!!!